# AngularJS Services 404 Error

Tags: angularjs, service

So I am trying to connect to my services, but I am getting a 404 Not Found error. Here is the error:

```
GET http://192.168.24.128/app/services/login?username=myUser&password=betatest 404 Not Found
```

Here is my directory:

```
- app
-  - app
-  - css
-  - dialogs
-  - fonts
-  - images
-  - js
-  - partials
-  - secure
-  - services
-  -  - .htaccess
-  -  - api.php
-  -  - Rest.inc.php
```

Here is my service factory, which I successfully hit because I get the confirm dialog to pop up:

```
app.factory("services", ['$http', function ($http) {
    var serviceBase = '/app/services/';
    var obj = {};

    obj.attemptLogin = function(username, password){
        confirm('service factory attemptLogin');
        return $http.get(serviceBase + 'login?username=' + username + '&password=' + password);
    }

    return obj;
}]);
```

Here is my controller:

```
app.controller('loginModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, $modalInstance, $log, modalOptions, services) {

    $scope.modalOptions = modalOptions;

    $scope.login = function (result) {
        if (result.username && result.password) {

            $log.info('Attempting login in as: ' + result.username + ' on ' + new Date());

            services.attemptLogin(result.username, result.password).then( function(msg) {
                if (msg.status == 200 && msg.data && msg.data.role) {
                    $log.info('Username/Password Matched!');
                    $rootScope.userProfile = msg.data;
                    $scope.modalOptions.loginFailed = false;
                    $modalInstance.close(result);
                } else {
                    $log.info('Username/Password did not match');
                    $scope.modalOptions.loginFailed = true;
                    // TODO Blank out username/password
                    $scope.modalOptions.loginFailed = true;
                }
            });
        }
    };

    $scope.cancel = function () {
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
});
```

Is there anything that looks out of place to anyone? Any help is much appreciated because I've been fiddling with this for hours.

EDIT (.htaccess):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php?x=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php [QSA,NC,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php [QSA,NC,L]   
</IfModule>
```

Comment: seem to be looking in the wrong place...is htaccess set to point at one of the files in that directory?

Comment: Ahhh... That could possibly be it. I'm out right now, when I get back home I'll check that out and update. Thanks charlietfl

Comment: Okay I added the .htaccess file. I guess I don't see what is wrong with it. @charlietfl

Comment: Well it works fine uploaded to the server, but running locally it had a problem. If anyone knows why it's not working on the virtual machine I'd really appreciate the help.